# Suppress line in legend - Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I have a piece of code to make a plot in Matlab:

```
x = linspace(0,pi);
y1 = cos(x);
plot(x,y1,'b')

hold on 
y2 = cos(2*x);
plot(x,y2,'r')

legend({'\color{blue}cos(x)','\color{red}cos(2x)'})
```

[image]

How to completely suppress the blue and red lines in the legend?
I want cos(x) in red and cos(2x) in blue without lines.